# Using AJAX to send javascript variable to php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a HTML webpage that  has some radio buttons along with a recover button. The radio buttons have a string assigned to them. When I select a radio button and click the recover button, I want to pass the value of that radio button to a php file. the php file is located in the same place as the web page.

**Recover button**

```
<button id="recover" type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="recovercall()">Recover Files</button>
```

**recovercall() method**

```
function recovercall() {    

        var radioName = $("input[name=inputWalls]:checked").val()

            $.ajax({ url: 'recover.php',

                 data: { radioName : radioName },

                 type: 'POST',

                 success: function(output) {

                              alert(output);
                          }
        });
}
```

The radio name variable contains the correct values as i have tested it.

**PHP Code**

```
 if(isset($_POST['radioName'])) {

         $rname = $_POST['radioName'];

         run_script($rname);
 }


 function run_script($rname) {

     if (!$return) {

         echo "Script ran Successfully";

         echo $rname;

     } else {

           echo "There was an error processing the file";

     }
```

When I select the radio button and click on the recover button, nothing happens. I have checked the network tab in the console and can see the error

POST http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/xxxxxx/recover.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

I am using AJAX for another button and that works fine. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I see not closed `}` for function definition.

Comment: if this is all your php code then you have a **parse** error....  *parse error, unexpected $end(), expecting '}'!*

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. damn that bracket!!. Thanks guys